# Why aren't tendons affected by chronic tendinopathy replaced by artificial tendons?

Tags: tendons

A fair amount of patients suffer from chronic tendinopathy. Why aren't defectuous tendons replaced by artificial tendons?

Answer (score 4):

Tendons don't usually get replaced because there is tendon repair surgery instead. Getting your tendon (or any body part for that matter) replaced by an artificial tendon usually takes longer to recover than a tendon repair surgery, and also leaves you with some lifetime limitations, such as not be able to lift weight and you will not be able to compete in sports that involve the tendon that got replaced as actively. Tendon repair surgeries tend to take less time to recover from, and they also have a high success rate (if you do proper therapy).

---

<sup>[Tendon Repair Surgery](http://www.healthline.com/health/tendon-repair)</sup>

<sup>[Hand Surgery: Replacement and Tendon Repair](http://www.uwmedicine.org/health-library/Pages/hand-surgery-replacement-and-tendon-repair.aspx)</sup>